# How to extract a random number from every value in a column of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

**Sample data**

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(5, 0, 5), y = runif(5,0,5))

         x         y
1 1.437888 0.2277825
2 3.941526 2.6405274
3 2.044885 4.4620952
4 4.415087 2.7571751
5 4.702336 2.2830737
```

I would like to create a column `z` in which from all y-values a random number is subtracted between `0` and the value of `y` itself.

**Approach**

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>% mutate(z = y - runif(n=1, min=0, max=y))
```

**Problem**

The random number is only generated once and subsequently extracted from all y-values, while I would like to generate a random number for each subtraction.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can generate all random numbers together and then subtract.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(rand = runif(n=n(), min=0, max=y), z = y - rand)

#         x         y      rand          z
#1 1.437888 0.2277825 0.1573306 0.07045192
#2 3.941526 2.6405274 2.1004535 0.54007390
#3 2.044885 4.4620952 0.1098286 4.35226662
#4 4.415087 2.7571751 1.3173671 1.43980793
#5 4.702336 2.2830737 1.7316190 0.55145467
```

Keeping `rand` column to confirm we have different random number for every row.

In base R, we can do

```
transform(df, z = y - runif(nrow(df), min = 0, max = y))
```

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestions! I noticed that changing `n=1` to `n()` in `df %>% mutate(z = y - runif(n=1, min=0, max=y))` also worked, but I actually do not understand why?

Comment: @user213544 yes, it would work I just made a separate step here for clarity. The reason why only one number is selected is because `mutate` call is done only once for entire dataframe. If you add `rowwise` your attempt would work. `df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(z = y - runif(n=1, min=0, max=y))`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `sapply` the random number is not maintained:

```
df$z <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(t) df$y[t] - runif(n=1, min=0, max=df$y[t]))

df
      x         y          z
1 4.3658120 3.4449822 0.33968580
2 3.2087255 0.3607723 0.06576989
3 0.8543368 1.2724004 0.14831275
4 1.0649560 0.2387039 0.04146824
5 3.6421655 2.2787097 1.48823688
```

To check

```
3.4449822 - 0.33968580 = 3.105296
2.2787097 - 1.48823688 = 0.7904728
0.2387039 - 0.04146824 = 1.488237
```